# wordpress Https always is redirect to http

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have a website hosted on aws lighsail server, which use the bitnami wordpress. 
I just install ssl certificate on the apache2, then every time I go to the HTTPS home page, then I am always redirected to http.

[HomePage](https://heyvr.com.au/)

but if I login [Manage Login Page](https://heyvr.com.au/wp-login), then it works.

I think this is a setup issue on the wordpress side instead on the apache side.

Can anyone give me some help to figure out the issue.

Comment: Did you change the site URL and home URL in the Wordpress settings? This can be done on the settings page, you can force those in the wp-config.php or you can do it directly in the database (https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/).

Answer (score 0):

to do this you have to set up your server to force https connection, after you have installed ssl certificate. Sometimes, in the same page of ssl certificate there is an option to force https. You can contact your hosting.
In alternative, you can force https by editing .htaccess file in your website root (by code editor of your hosting or via ftp). You have to add this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Another alternative is the installation of the plugin Really Simple SSL, but I don’t like this option for future updates.

I hope this answer is helpful :)

Comment: In addition isn't there a setting in wordpress as to the address of the website in which case you need to specify https://... ?

Comment: This is a Lightsail guide about "https" [https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-tls-ssl-certificates-in-lightsail-https]. By default http connections are accepted. The best way to do this is by code line in .htaccess (File manager --> public_html of your domain). Follow step 2 of this guide [https://wpbarista.com/force-wordpress-ssl-https/]